# How to disable autofill in angular 7 project

Tags: angular, google-chrome, autofill

I am trying to disable Google Chrome's auto-fill feature, and have tried the solutions posted on StackOverflow. All these solutions, successful or not, work for a single form/form-input. But I need a one shot method to disable the feature using a single line/block of code that will work across the project.

Comment: `autocomplete="false"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084770/disable-autofill-autocomplete-with-angular-form-and-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 0):

> this is a browser feature

see this answer [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)